# Vim : time increment in a schedule

Tags: regex, datetime, vim, vim-macros

I'm new to Vim and I'm trying to see what I can / can't do with it. I would like to increment a list of times like this :

```
09:00 Breakfast 
09:30 RSS 
09:50 Stretch
10:00 Main proj
13:00 food
14:00 Main proj...
```

Lets say I woke up too late, and I'd like to quickly increment everything by 45 minutes in Vim

I tried a macro :

- Time in minutes : `09:00 -> 09 * 60 + 00`
- `+ 45`
- SUM with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>
- Trying to reformat it `(int)SUM/60 : SUM - ((int)SUM/60)*60`

But I couldn't get it to work (it is such a long macro) and I'm quicker at doing it manually.

On top of that, even if I succeed I can't figure out how to keep the `"0"` of `"09"` to keep my numbers in a column.

Is it possible in Vim ? Maybe a regex ?

**[edit]** For the purpose of exercise, I'd rather use macros, a regex, or even a function in VimScript than a plugin

Comment: Just because its possible to do something in vim doesnt mean that you should. This operation seems more like something to be done using miscellaneous unix tools, or even libreoffice-calc.

Comment: it's a shame, I was hoping for some Vim wizardry ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I tried in a regex ( remove return carriage) :

```
%s@\(\d\d\):\(\d\d\)@\=printf('%.2d:%.2d'((submatch(1)*60+submatch(2)+45)/60),
((submatch(1)*60+submatch(2)+45)-((submatch(1)*60+submatch(2)+45)/60)*60))@
```

it's quite inelegant and i'd like to have  `inc = 45` and `sum = (submatch(1)*60+submatch(2)+inc)`, I would need to declare the variables on the same line as the printf... but it works ;)

Inside visual selection  : with `'<,'>` instead of `%`.

One problem of course is that it doesnt loop back around midnight, but I guess for that @steffen's answer would be better

**Edit :** I found that modulo existed in Vimscript and I couldn't resist...now it loops around midnight :

```
%s@\(\d\d\):\(\d\d\)@\=printf('%.2d:%.2d',((submatch(1)*60+submatch(2)+45)/60)%24,
(submatch(1)*60+submatch(2)+45)%60)@
```

**Edit 2:** And here is the code in a function using the func-range (thanks @Kent)

```
function! IncrementTime(mins) range
    "Increments time within a range ( current line or selection)
    let pat = '(submatch(1)*60+submatch(2)+'.a:mins.'+1440)'
    execute a:firstline.','.a:lastline.'s@\(\d\d\):\(\d\d\)@\=printf("%.2d:%.2d",('.pat.'/60)%24,'.pat.'%60)@'
endfunction
```

I had to add 1440 to avoid negative hours when one decrements

Answer (score 2):

I just found OP's new edit, it seems that he is looking for a little vimscript function. Here is one, NOT generic function, however it works for your needs.

Note, after the minute increment, the result could be greater (later) than `24:00` in this case, the `date` info will be lost, an example is adding `45mins` on `23:30` will result `00:15`

```
function! IncTime(mins) 
    let pat = '^\d\d:\d\d\ze '
    for i in range(line('$'))
        let tss = matchstr(getline(i+1), pat)
        if tss
            let ts = split(tss,':')
            let ns = 60*ts[0] + ts[1] + a:mins
            let nts = printf('%.2d:%.2d', (ns/60)%24, ns % 60)
            execute i+1.'s/'.pat.'/'.nts
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
```

source it, and in your file call `:call IncTime(45)` to check the changes applied. You can also pass different offset other than `45` to the function, like `10`, or even `2000`

[image]

Comment: Thanks and do you know how do I allow the function to work within the Visual selection ? I tried `\%V` but it didn't seem to work

Comment: @irrelevantfish my function check all lines in your buffer.  If you want it to work for selection, you have to change it to accept range, and pass range info to the function.  read `:h func-range`

Comment: Thanks, got it to work with `func-range`, I posted my own answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only (or write function as Kent commented) with some plugins, like this:

[Speeddating plugin](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/vim-editor-how-to-increase-or-decrease-date-time-roman-number-and-ordinals/)

Comment: the word "**only**" should be removed.

Comment: Do you really can write such macro? I want to look at it

Comment: if I do it, I won't use macro. I would write a function.

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, it's a way too... More complicated, but still.

Comment: it depends on how do you define complicated. I am not saying a plugin is not good solution, but a little function can do it to achieve OP's requirement  for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Date and time calculations always turn out to be more difficult than expected. Think of daylight savings for instance. You should let some other tool make the calculations. If you're on Linux, you could try to this with `date`:

```
let @a=substitute(system("date -d @$(($(date -d " . substitute(getline('.'), '\(\S\+\).*', '\1', '') . " +\\%s)+45*60)) +\\%H:\\%M"), ".$", "", "")
```

This will add 45 Minutes to the time in the beginning of the current line (delimited by space) and put it into register `a`. Your macro could then delete the time and replace it with @a:

```
"_dE
"aP0
```

BTW: This would also work with a string like "now":

```
09:00 Breakfast (before)
09:45 Breakfast (after)

now Breakfast (before)
14:45 Breakfast (after)
```